# Why is there 'CR' in Stack Overflow HTML code?

Tags: discussion, support, code

I was using Inspect Element to look through Stack Overflow's HTML code.

While doing that, I spotted 'CR' at the end of each line:

[image: Image 1]

Just curious, what does this represent or is it a rendering error?

---

**Browser:** Safari Version 10.0
**OS:** macOS Sierra 10.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CR stands for [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). I have seen it on other sites where the servers are running Windows. Remember, macOS uses just a Line Feed to indicate a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), so it might think the CR in the CR+LF served by Windows is superfluous.

Comment: That explains it, I think El Capitan didn't display it, maybe Sierra explicitly indicates it's a newline